# Webflux parallel connections somehow limited to 256

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I have a simple setup of server and client:

```
Flux.range(1, 5000)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(i -> WebClient.create()
            .method(HttpMethod.POST)
            .uri("http://localhost:8080/test")
            .body(Mono.just(String.valueOf(i)), String.class)
            .exchange())
        .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .subscribe(response ->
            response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .subscribe(body -> log.info("{}", body)));
```

here is the client:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<String> test(@RequestBody Mono<String> body) {
    return body.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
}
```

Both things run on netty. Maybe someone has an idea what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not due to a `WebClient` limitation about connection pools, but this actually comes from a Reactor implementation details that you can change.

By default, Reactor operators such as `flatMap` have `prefetch=32` (the number of elements we request before the end subscriber asks for those) and `maxConcurrency=256` (the maximum number of elements processed concurrently by the operator).

You can use variants of `Flux.flatMap(Function mapper, int concurrency, int prefetch)` to change that behavior.

Your code snippet is using a mix of `subscribeOn` and `publishOn`; I'd say that given you're doing reactive I/O work with this code snippet, you shouldn't try to schedule work on an elastic/parallel scheduler. Removing those operators is best here.

Comment: Thanks man, I thought I should leave the http nio threads when I'm doing sth else.